# Making Framework (not Core, not Standard) NuGet packages with VS2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, nuget, packaging

If I make a .NET Core or .NET Standard project using VS2017, and open the project's properties, there's a "Package" tab, which includes a checkbox labeled "Generate NuGet package on build".  But there's no such tab if it's a .NET Framework project.

Am I missing something here? Or for a Framework project, do I have to go through the whole manual nuspec/pack/blah blah rigamarole?

Comment: Yes. If you use non-SDK type project files, you simply have to go through the whole manual process. Nothing changes for those old stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Making Framework (not Core, not Standard) NuGet packages with VS2017

That is because the .NET Framework project still use the old project type (Non-SDK), the Package tab is only supported by new project type(SDK).

If you want to use the Package tab for library .NET Framework project, you can **convert your project from the old .csproj to new .csproj**, (Right click your project->Unload project->Edit .csproj. Replace the contents of your csproj with the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Note**: Need to delete the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in the Properties.

See [Old csproj to new csproj: Visual Studio 2017 upgrade guide](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) for more info about convert old .csproj to new .csproj.

Then you will get the package tab for .NET Framework project:

[image]

Hope this helps.